# Is it possible to use jnlp without signing the jars?

Tags: java, security, jar, jnlp, unsigned

Is there any way at all to use jnlp without having to sign the jars involved?

(The application is being used in a secure environment so from the security point of view signing is not necessary)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, however the webstart application will be in 'sandbox' mode and cannot access filesystem, network and many other parts of the OS. Simply leave out the security element to accomplis this.

> security Element
>
> Each application is,
>   by default, run in a restricted
>   execution environment, similar to the
>   Applet sandbox.  The security element
>   can be used to request unrestricted
>   access.
>
> If the all-permissions element is
>   specified, the application will have
>   full access to the client machine and
>   local network. If an application
>   requests full access, then all JAR
>   files must be signed. The user will be
>   prompted to accept the certificate the
>   first time the application is
>   launched.

Comment: Does this apply to `Java 8 u 66` as well??