# How to prevent loading of unsigned jars?

Tags: java, security, jar-signing

In my application, noticed that among signed jar files even unsigned jar file are also getting loaded while invoke application, so to ensure the security i need guidance to prevent loading of any unsigned jars

**EDIT:**

`How to identify / retrieve the Jar signature using ClassLoader`

Comment: why type of application? applets, standalone, web?

Comment: @user2310289 Standalone java application launch through jnlp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [jarverifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374170/how-to-verify-a-jar-signed-with-jarsigner-programmatically) in the link, to check whether the jar has completely signed not and at the same time it can be used to verify the certificate of jar file.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve this using the all-permissions element in your jnlp file.

```
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html and [Is it possible to use jnlp without signing the jars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096444/is-it-possible-to-use-jnlp-without-signing-the-jars)

Hope it helps.

Comment: my jnlp already having this element, but application still allows to load unsigned jars  , this is not working

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a custom version of JarClassLoader which will check jars signatures.